# C linux internal difference between O_WRONLY and O_RDWR if only writting

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I know open offers these mutually exclusive flags: `O_RDONLY`,  `O_WRONLY` and  `O_RDWR`.

I want to know: Are there any performance issues (even of it's just a fraction of a ms) or different ways of treating the file if the file is opened as `O_RDWR` and

- I only write to the file. (Versus opening as O_WRONLY)
- I only read data from the file. (Versus opening as O_RDONLY)

Comment: Did you try it?  What were your results?

Comment: It would be interesting if there were different caching or readahead rules depending on the flags used. But I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @carl-norum I tried and there is no API or programatically difference (except that if I open as O_RDONLY and I try to write write would return -1 and if I open as O_WRONLY and try to read, read return -1). That's why I asked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you seem to have mistyped (inverted) in the two cases of your description the write/read tags. As to what you ask, the VFS, in its various structures, keeps track of desired access rights by flags. The read/write flag is typically a different bit in the same flag (multi) byte. When a process request access as read or write, the kernel checks if it has the requested access rights, and proceeds accordingly. As setting 2 bits doesn't increase your execution time, you should see no difference as later access is the same. Using the proper tag is simply good style and part of file protection.

Comment: "First, you seem to have mistyped (inverted) in the two cases of your description the write/read tags" Ups, true, fixed.

Comment: Kay, so it's seems like they are different only for permissions execution (so that if I only have write permitions I can open for write (using: O_WRONLY)and not getting access denied because I cannot read it (I would get access denied if I used O_RDWR)

Comment: Pretty much, at least in x86 architecture and 2.6 kernel, but probably also on other architectures and the newer 3.x kernel.